# How to use wildcards in child path using Zapier querying Firebase Realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, mailgun, zapier

I am attempting to use zapier to send an order confirmation email with mailgun whenever an order is written to the firebase RTDB.

The child path in the RTDB is Orders/{userid}/{timestamp}/.  How do I declare the userid and timestamp as wildcards in the child path in zapier.  Right now, it expects all new entries to come from the user id and the timestamp I used when setting it up in the first place.

I hope this makes sense.  If it does not, I will do my best to try to rephrase to make it clear what I'm going for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on an outside look of the Zapier triggers, searches and actions for Firebase, it seems that their backend relies on the Firebase Client SDK. Because of this, you won't be able to use wildcards in the way you expect because each path is listened to in a static manner.

Instead, you might have to consider using [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/).

The [Postmark](https://postmarkapp.com) team have a pretty solid tutorial on how to do this [here](https://postmarkapp.com/blog/sending-transactional-emails-via-firebase-and-cloud-functions). There is also another question [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44259405) that does what you are looking for using functions. It shouldn't be too difficult to swap Postmark out for the [mailgun-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailgun-js) library.

Comment: It's also important to note that this requires billing to be enabled on your Firebase project unless you use `nodemailer` with a Gmail account.